# Iterated Sine... Further expansion

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, functions

We all can find the classical approximation of the iterated sine :

$$\text{Let } \sin^n(x) = \sin(\sin(\sin(.... \sin(x))))\:\:n\:\text{times.} \\ $$
Then:
$$\sin^n(x) = \sqrt{\frac3n} + o\left(\frac 1{\sqrt n}\right)$$

And a further approximation [here](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~gelineau/devagreg/Sinus_itere.pdf) gives :

$$\sin^n(x) = \sqrt{\frac3n} - \frac {3\sqrt3\:\ \ln(n)}{10\:n \sqrt n} + o\left(\frac {\ln(n)}{n\:\sqrt n}\right) $$
which is still independent from the initial value $x$ (assumed to be between 0 and π/2 for simplicity).

I am using the method described in this paper to push it further :
$$\frac1{sin^2(u_n)} - \frac1{u_n^2} = \frac13 + \frac{u_n^2}{15} + \frac{u_n^4}{189} + \frac{2\:u_n^4}{189} +o(u_n^5)  $$
Now we can replace $u_n^2$ by its approximation $ \frac n3+ \frac{\ln(n)}5 + o(\ln(n))$
and sum from 0 to n (with $u_0$ = x )

Which gives me :
$$\frac1{\sin^n(x)^2}- \frac1{x^2} = \frac n3 + \frac{\ln (n)}5 + constant + o(\frac 1n)$$
and finally 
$$\sin^n(x) = {\bigg[\frac n3 + \frac{\ln (n)}5 + \frac1{x^2} + constant + o(\frac 1n)\:\:\bigg]} ^{-1/2}$$
Where x appears after the term in $\ln(n)$ and fades out as $n^{-3/2}$. The constant involves Euler constant and other limits of convergent series.

Q: Is this wrong ? Did I miss something ? Has anybody pushed the approximation of the iterated sine further ?

Comment: You must be assuming $0 < x < \pi$ for these approximations to work: obviously if you started at $x=0$ or $\pi$ all iterations would be $0$, and if you started in $(-\pi, 0)$ all would be negative.

Comment: The initial value $x$ does not *need* to appear in the estimate because after the first iteration, no matter how large $x$ is, $\sin x$ will be less than one in absolute value.  However since since sine is an odd function, if at some point the iteration gives a negative value in $[-1,0)$, the remaining iterates will also be negative   So we ought to specify a starting value in $(0,1]$ to justify your claim.

Comment: I suspect that the asymptotics can be carried arbitrarily far without explicit $x$-dependence.  The catch is that the $\mathscr o(\ldots)$ term hides the dependence on $x$: it is $\mathscr o(\ldots)$ as $n \to \infty$ for any fixed $x \in (0,\pi)$, but the $N$ such that this term is less than $\epsilon (\ldots)$ for $n > N$ will depend on $x$, and in particular must go to $\infty$ as $x \to 0+$.

Comment: Thanks Robert. However the way the approximation is derived there appears a u0 ( initial value of the series, = x ) which effectively disappears, "erased" by the n/3 or ln(n) ...but one suspects that 'once' the relevant power is beyond 1/n^2 the series sum becomes finite and x 'stays'... ??

Comment: Your suspicion that as the approximation is furthered, the $x$ will (re)appear "in the development" is somewhat contrary to the intent of developing a dependence on iterate index $n$, with diminishing relation to the $x = u_0$ where we started.  As Dr. Israel explains, this dependence on $x$ is real, but it is hidden in the $o(\ldots)$ notation, and thus reduced to an unstated constant (one that grows, perhaps counterintuitively, with $x \to 0+$).

Comment: How about doing this:  Asymptotics as $n \to \infty$ for $\sin^n(\pi/2) - \sin^n(\pi/4)$ .  Will the first term of this tell you where "$x$" appears in the original question?

Comment: Working on it while I'm posting// On the basis of the asymptotic method. Will post next step in Answers soon. I'd like to get reactions... Did I miss something ?